# How to stack results froma query in an Object-Oriented fashion

Tags: php, css

These are some of the inline-styles.

```
  body{
        font-family: helvetica;
        font-size: 12px;
        font-weight: normal;
        color: gold;
        margin: 0;
        padding:0;
        background: black;
    }

p{
    font-family: helvetica;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: white;
    margin: 0;
    padding-top: 5px;
    line-height: 14px;

}
header{
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: red;
    border-bottom: 2px solid gold;
}
```

/* I would like to add a height to this wrapper, but when I do, the while loop doesn't stack the products in a row of 3. It just lists the products straight down the page. */

```
#wrapper{
    width:618px;
    margin: 10px auto;
    /*background: yellow;*/
}
#stack{
    width:201px;
    height:200px;
    float: left;
    margin-right:5px;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    padding:0;
    text-align:center;
    /* background:pink;*/
}
a{
    cursor:pointer;
    color: gold;
    text-decoration: none;
}
h3{
    width:618px;
    height:30px;
    font-family: helvetica;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color:21a4ff;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align:center;
    padding-top:10px;

}
p.price{
    font-weight: bold;
    color: tomato;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height:10px;
}
p.name{
    font-family: helvetica;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: gold;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    line-height: 12px;
}
</style>

<?php

include("mysql.connect.php");

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT sku, name, price, sm_image 
                            FROM products ORDER BY price");
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($sku, $name, $price, $sm_image);
```

This is where my problem is. How can I set this while loop to list results in rows of three using the $stmt-fetch()) method?

```
while($stmt->fetch()){
    echo "<div id='wrapper'>
            <div id='stack'>
                <img src='$sm_image'></img><br>
                <p>$sku</p>
                <p class='name'>$name</p>
                <p class='price'>$$price<br></p>
            </div>";
    echo "</div>";
}

// Recuperate the statement resources
$stmt->close();

// Close the connection
$mysqli->close();



?>
```

Comment: ???? `$$price` Do you really have a `$$` there

Comment: I echoed the dollar sign for the variable.

Comment: Try adding display: inline-block and float: left to the wrapper id

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't work. It's actually a while loop problem. I need to set the loop results in rows of 3. I have a book that shows me how to do it another way without prepared statements. But I need to do this example with prepared statements. Any suggestions?